# An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, sockets, websocket

Hello I'm newbie for symfony frame work.

currently using  Symfony version 3.4.

I'm implementing websockets to my project using `Gos Web Socket Bundle` (https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle) and documentation also.

after run this command

```
`php bin/console gos:websocket:server`
```

getting message like this.

```
`Failed to listen on "tcp://127.0.0.1:8080": An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access
   permissions.`
```

in config.yml added this

```
`# Web Socket Configuration
gos_web_socket:
    server:
        port: 8080        #The port the socket server will listen on
        host: 127.0.0.1   #The host ip to bind to`
```

If I changed port no `8080` to `80` I will get any error from command prompt but in browser it doesn't work. If I used `8080`  websocket server is not running. Help me out! spent whole full day on this.

Comment: Could it be that you have to specify a route, like in this example from the docs? https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle/blob/master/Resources/docs/RPCSetup.md#step-3-register-your-service-with-pubsubrouter

Comment: Alternatively the port 8080 might already be in use by another service like a local webserver.

Comment: @dbrumann using the routes

Comment: @dbrumann if used 8080 getting error `HTTP ERROR 426` message like `This page isn’t working`

Comment: use `netstat -ano | findstr :8080`  to see who is using it

Answer (score 0):

Without being a `root` (or via `sudo`) you are not allowed to listen to privileged ports (`<1024`).

As for the port `8080` check if there is another service already running on it:

```
lsof -i :8080
```

Have you tried selecting another port, for example, `8888`?

Hope this helps...

Comment: I'm trying in windows system

Comment: stackoverflow.com/q/56338792/8631622 Please look into this problem. I did everything I could. But I could not solve this problem @Jovan Perovic